# Inserção de objeto complexo EF Core com WebAPI

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação WebAPI (.NET) com EntityFramework Core.
Fiz a implementação das seguintes entidades:

*Pais.cs*

```
public class Pais
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100), Required]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

*Estado.cs*

```
public class Estado
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
}
```

*Cidade.cs*

```
public class Cidade
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Ao tentar inserir um novo registro com o JSON abaixo:

```
{
    "descricao": "Ribeirão Preto",
    "estado": {
        "id": 1,
        "pais": {
            "id": 1,
            "descricao": "Brasil"
        },
        "descricao": "São Paulo",
        "sigla": "SP"
    }
}
```

Tenho o seguinte retorno `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Pais' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

Ao que me parece o sistema está tentando inserir o Pais que está relacionado a cidade do JSON, mas não estou entendo o porque disso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O EntityFramework está tentando adicionar um novo `Pais`, e como não está explícito que é o EF quem deve criar os IDs, o EF está esperando que o Id de País seja `null` ou `0`, passando assim a responsabilidade do repositório em criar esse Id.

Porém, não é essa sua intênção. Vc apenas quer adicionar uma `Cidade`. Um `workaround` é, antes de adicionar o novo registro `Cidade` no EF, faça uma consulta por `Estado` e vincule ao novo objeto:

```
var estado = dbContext.Estados.Single(estado => estado.Id == novaCidade.Estado.Id);
novaCidade.Estado = estado;
dbContext.Cidades.Add(novaCidade);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Assim seu EF irá saber que a nova `Cidade` possui relação direta com um registro pai já existente em seu repositório.

Mas para realmente acertar tudo isso, revise como vc está configurando seu EF. Considere talvez, ou adicionar um `EstadoId` na classe `Cidade`, ou criar modelos de repositorio diferentes dentro do escopo do repositorio - o que irá exigir grande esforço no desenvolvimento, mas o resultado é ótimo.

Comment: Então, mas eu não estou passando o id da cidade no json acima. Sendo assim não era para ele gerar automaticamente? E pelo que entendo do erro, ele está tentando inserir o pais, sendo que esse já possui o id informado.

Comment: Lembrando que estou tentando adicionar uma nova cidade.

Comment: Editei a resposta, deve estar mais clara agora.

Comment: Show, agora deu certo. Eu só gostaria de saber mais uma coisa. 
Eu tenho mesmo que consultar novamente o objeto Estado? Porque como já passa as informações no JSON não via a necessidade de consultar.
Fora que isso pode afetar a performance da aplicação ou não?

Comment: Sim pode, mas isso é por conta da sua arquitetura. Se vc criar um propriedade `EstadoId` em `Cidade` e avisar pro EF que isso é uma chave estrangeira, não precisa da primeira consulta.